# How to update an instance in Django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a question about how I can update an instance in django rest framework.

So basically I want to update my user profile through an request but I cannot get current user Id. Is there a better way to get current user and update its information? This is not working because request.user is always anonymous.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def update_profile(request):

    serializer = AccountSerializer(request.user, data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: are you following a tutorial? Can you post more parts of your code? preferably the whole views.py for this app

Answer (score 1):

If `request.user` is always anonymous here, you could:

1. Check to see if `request.user.is_authenticated` before anything else and redirect unauthenticated users to a login page (or use a `@login_required` decorator), or
2. Get a `user` object based on data from a URL parameter/kwarg instead of basing it on the user making the request. For instance, perhaps `yourapp/users/1` grabs the `1` from the URL and uses for a primary key lookup.